# Qt Creator no option for Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I've installed the Qt Creator v2.6.2 based on Qt 4.8.3(32-bit). When I started new project, I couldn't find the "Qt C++ Application" tab.

it only shows libraries, other projects, Non-Qt projects and import projects

what am I missing here?

thx b4

Answer (score 5):

Go to **Tools -> Options -> Build & Run > Qt Versions** tab and check whether your installed Qt versions are recognized or not. If the list is empty that means: for some reason Qt Creator has stopped detecting your Qt library.

To solve this problem, Press the "Add" button in that dialog "**Tools -> Options -> Build & Run > Qt Versions**" and locate your installed 'qmake.exe' file. It should be in the bin directory of where you installed the Qt library (e.g. C > Qt > 4.8.4 > bin > qmake.exe ). If still not recognized, you should look for the easiest way like installing "qt SDK" which takes care of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the qt installation in the creator options. It's tools -> options -> Build & Run -> Qt versions and add one if there's no bind installations. I am not sure whether that helps, but it's worth a try.

You can also create the project manually and import it into the creator.

Create a main.cpp file with contents like

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

And the create a .pro file, with contents:

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = Test

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

After that try to import your .pro file into the creator.

Comment: I've added the Qt versions from tools > options > build&run and added the path to qmake.exe, but the Qt version shows up with red '!' sign and a label > "Qt version is not properly installed, please run make install". I'm currently trying to create the project manually...

Comment: Jason, how did you install your qt bundle? Was it a binary install or did you download the source code? If it was a source code, have you compiled it?

Comment: just tried the 2nd option and it stopped in configuration setting. Qt said that "no valid kits found"....

Comment: I'm using this link https://qt-project.org/downloads. the library I downloaded was the Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Windows (minGW 4.4, 317 MB) and the Qt Creator I've installed is qt-creator-windows-opensource-2.6.2...

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't configured Qt building tools. You must have istalled Qt Creator, Qt libraries, MinGW compiler (for Qt 4 -- MinGW 4.4).

In Tools -> Options -> Build & Run you must specify all pathes (for MinGW compiler, for `qmake` and create tool chain to use MinGW compiler with concrete `qmake`). So, you'll have working tool chain to build Qt projects.

Good luck!

Comment: qmake.exe has been added to Qt version, but an error saying "Qt version is not properly installed, please run make install". I've also added the mingw compiler with compiler path C:\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe and restarted Qt. still no C++ Qt Application...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. It turns out that the qmake.exe which I pointed to is at the folder

```
C:\Qt\4.8.4\qmake\qmake.exe
```

which is wrong and the path should be

```
C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin\qmake.exe
```

now the "Qt C++ Application" has shown on the tab

thx for all the help b4